# Cannot Run as Administrator even when Domain Admin

Tags: administrator, windows-server-2012-r2, runas

I am part of the Administrators group on Windows Server 2012 R2 but whenever I try to run Powershell as an administrator I get prompted to log in and then get denied because my privileges need to be elevated.
I was able to add myself to the Domain Admins account but that still didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to log out and log back in for the changes to take place.